# Hibernate + nvl()= Oracle 01465

Tags: hibernate, encoding, entitymanager, nvl

Oracle error when attempting to execute a native SQL query that uses a null parameter value. I've boiled it down to this test case:

```
      String SQL_SELECT = 
        "select * from act t1 where t1.G074=:G074 AND t1.G542=:G542 AND 
        nvl(t1.svhlick,' ')=nvl(:svhlick,' ') 
        and  t1.svhlic=:svhlic 
        and t1.sf$version =
          (select max(sf$version) from act t2 where t2.G074=t1.G074 and t2.G542=t1.G542 AND nvl
        (t2.svhlick,' ')=nvl(t1.svhlick,' ') and t2.svhlic=t1.svhlic)";
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(SQL_SELECT, Act.class);
        ….
           q.setParameter("svhlick", entity.getSvhlick());
         …
```

the query uses Oracle's `NVL` function to handle `null` parameters.
However, when I run this code, it fails with an error on the `q.getResultList ()` call.

The error is as follows:

> ```
> ORA-01465:  invalid hex number
> ```

Now, i'm resolved this problem as

```
  q.setParameter("svhlick", (entity.getSvhlick() == null ? " " : entity.getSvhlick()));
```

But this'is solution is not good.

Database Oracle 11gR2  win1251 encoding.

Netbeans 7.3.1 project encoding UTF-8.

entity.getSvhlick() - String
svhlick in Oracle - varchar2(1)

I think the problem may be due to different encoding.

Any Help?

Comment: Use coalesce instead?

Comment: nvl(t1.svhlick,' ')=coalesce(:svhlick,' ') it's= ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY, received CHAR

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by specifiying the type like:

```
q.setParameter("svhlick", entity.getSvhlick(), StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
```

see https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=984725

Comment: apptaro. Thank you a lot for responce.